# Is there any way to output and log number of files deleted from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command

I have a shell script file called somefile.sh and it has the code something like below,

somefile.sh

```
find /xxx/yyy/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
find /xxx/zzz/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
find /xxx/xyx/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
find /xxx/xzx/* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

And this runs in a cron by daily basis,

Now I want to set up a log file for this,
like for each shell script I want to output my each command results to a file with  and then ,

Can anyone plese help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be trivial, isn't it?  Execute a shell command instead of `rm` and log whatever you want.

Comment: No I just put 4 commands there, but Actually I have some 10 number of folder to delete with different number of days. And I want to add this file to cronjob like delete daily basis. So I need file like this and need individual logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a folder list with expired day.

```
cat folder.list

/xxx/yyy  30
/xxx/zzz  30
/xxx/xyx  7
/xxx/xzx  14
```

update somefile.sh

```
LOG=/var/tmp/LOG

while read folder day X
do
    echo "Working on folder ${folder} .."
    find ${folder}/* -mtime +${day} -type f |while read line
    do
        echo "removing $line ...."
        rm ${line}
    done
done <folder.list >> $LOG
```

updated with new request (count the delete files)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

LOG=/var/tmp/LOG

while read folder day X
do
    echo "Working on folder ${folder} .."
    i=0
    find ${folder}/* -mtime +${day} -type f |while read line
    do
        echo "removing $line ...."
        rm ${line}
        ((i++))
    done
    echo "Totally deleted $i files in folder $folder"
done <folder.list >> $LOG
```

Comment: thanks for your response. This is really very very useful to me, but here how do I get number of files deleted?

Comment: You can init a count and increase it every time, when delete the file

Comment: you are saying something like this,
COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1)) ??

Comment: Ya thank you so much. And for logging with date? I just want to add date command in echo. right?

Comment: how do I mention the pattern to delete,
like "find /var/tmp/log_update* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;" and "find /var/tmp/*.sql -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;"

Comment: `find /var/tmp/ -name "log_update*" -mtime +30` and `find /var/tmp -name "*.sql" -mtime +30`

Answer (score 1):

Let your find print what it deletes

```
find /xxx/zzz/* -mtime +30 -print -exec rm {} \;
```

or

```
find /xxx/zzz/* -mtime +30 -exec echo Removing +30 days file {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

Next you can filter the output (wc -l or grep -c) the way you want.